# Checking a proof about the structure of the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, similar-matrices

Artin's "Algebra" book (1st ed, page 114, Proposition 2.9b) claims that given any $m\times n$ matrix A, there're matrices $Q \in GL_m(F)$ and $P \in GL_n(F)$ so that $QAP^{-1}$ has the form:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
I_r & O_{n-r} \\\\
O_{m-r} & O_{m-r,n-r}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

where $I_r$ is the $r\times r$ identity matrix, $O_{n-r}$, $O_{m-r}$, $O_{m-r,n-r}$ are matrices of zeros of sizes $(n-r)\times (n-r)$, $(m-r)\times (m-r)$, and $(m-r)\times (n-r)$, respectively, and $r$ is the rank of the associated linear transformation (i.e. the dimension of its column space).

The book claims this can be proved by matrix manipulation and I have attempted it. The one point I believe may be weak or not appropriately developed is claiming that the dimension of the column space of the row-echelon form of a matrix $A$, is the same as the one from $A$. I highlighted it below in bold.

---

**Proof attempt:**

There is a series of elementary row operations that take $A$ to its row echelon form, which can be expressed as left multiplication by the corresponding elementary matrices:

$$({E_q} \cdots {E_1})A:= QA$$

and let $s$ be the number of rows left that are not all zero.

Similarly, by a series of elementary column operations, every column that does not contain a pivot, can be zero-ed. Such operations can be expressed as right multiplication by the corresponding elementary matrices:

$$QA({E_p}^\prime \cdots {E_1}^\prime):=QAP^{-1}$$

**The number of non-zero columns is the number of l.i. vectors in the columns of $A$, this is, $r$.**

What's left to be proved it that $r=s$, but this is so because $r\leq \textrm{dim}(F^s)=s$, and at the same time $s\leq \textrm{dim}(F^r)=r$.

Comment: Artin presents this proposition in two equivalent forms, and the other (2.9a, in the same page), which is expressed in vector space form, is the one he details the proof for. I was following his indication to prove this alternative matrix form here as an exercise.

Comment: Looks good to me.